# Limit the scope of a GUI Extension DataExtender to the History View

Tags: gui-extensions, web8.5

I’m currently creating a `DataExtender` which shows an additional column, `UserComments`, in the History Popup window.
Because this column is already part of the dataset, this extension only consists of the config file, no additional JavaScript or `DataExtender` code.

To limit the extenders scope, I’m looking for the view name of this window, I think.
When using a wildcard, the column shows up correctly in the history view, but unfortunately also in all other views.

```
<ext:apply>
  <ext:view name="*" />
</ext:apply>`
```

When using the view name `ItemHistoryListDialogView` the column is not showing at all.

```
<ext:apply>
  <ext:view name="ItemHistoryListDialogView" />
</ext:apply>`
```

I have found this name by looking at `$display.getView().getId()` in the Chrome debugger.

How can find the correct view name, or otherwise limit the scope, preferably without additional code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SDL R&D provided the correct viewname: HistoryListDialogPopup.
I also learned that one may get this from one of the urls, when watching the network in chrome,  shows the viewname as value of the parameter forView
http://cms.local//WebUI/Editors/CME/Xml/ListDefinitions/historylist-head.xml?forView=HistoryListDialogPopup&forControl=FilteredItemsList

Answer (score -1):

Please try below code for getId().

> ```
> var p = this.properties;
> var c = p.controls;
> var item = $display.getItem();
> var filterColumns = $const.ColumnFilter.ALLOWED_ACTIONS;
> var list = item.getVersionList(filterColumns);
> p.listId = list.getId();
> ```

Comment: Unfortunately this gives me an undefined on the  1st line.